# Saving txt file to a user-defined location in Java SWT

Tags: java, swt

I am making a simple java application using SWT GUI to save a txt file to a user defined location. When a button is clicked, I open the directories like this:

```
DirectoryDialog directoryDialog = new DirectoryDialog(shell);

directoryDialog.setFilterPath(selectedDir);
directoryDialog.setMessage("Please select a directory and click OK");

String dir = directoryDialog.open();
```

Now I need to be able to make a file and save it to that location. How can I make and save to the user given location?

Comment: Your question is insufficiently specified.  What do you mean by "make a file?"  Can it be just any ol' file, or does it have a structure?

Comment: a txt. I just want to put a write to a txt file and save it to that location defined by the user

Comment: Apparently there's a bunch of ways to do it.  This article seems to be the most coherent: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/